# Unknown provider: $resourceProvider Error when calling angular service from outer js method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, javascript-injection

I'm trying to retrieve a value from an angular service in a function outside my angular app. The service looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.services').factory('MyService', [ '$resource', function ($resource) {

    return {

        getModuleId: function() {
            return $resource('/api/module_id', {}, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET'
                }});
        }

    }
}]);
```

Then in an html file, inside a `<script>` tag, I use the following code to call it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    moduleId = angular.injector(['ng', 'myApp.services']).get("MyService").getModuleId();
    ...
})
```

But this throws the error mentioned in the title:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- MyService
```

If I remove `'$resource'` from the Service (therefore the service has no injections) the error disappears. But I need to make it work with the injection there.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the module ngResource

```
 angular.module('myApp.services',[ngResource]).factory('MyService', [ '$resource', function ($resource) {

return {

    getModuleId: function() {
        return $resource('/api/module_id', {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET'
            }});
    }

}
```

}]);